# How to create new macros for combination of several keys

Tags: winedt, shortcut

I am using WinEdt 10.3. I previously used WinEdt 7.1. For WinEdt 7.1 I have configured macros for combination of several keys. For example, in WinEdt 7.1 in order for an \jour to appear when you press "Alt + j", you had to add blok “ITEM="jour" MACRO="Ins('\jour ');" SHORTCUT="Alt+j"“ to the MainMenu.ini.
If it is possible to create a similar command in for WinEdt 10.3, then how to do it?
Thank you in advance!